# Segmentation fault in C++ LFSR program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have made this ugly code for a Linear Feedback Shift Register. My knowledge of C++ is limited. Where is the cause of the segmentation fault?

```
operSeq = inpSeq;
 do {
  for ( unsigned int j=0; xorArray.size(); j=j+2 )
  {
  bit[4] = operSeq[xorArray[j]];
  bit[4] = bit[4] ^ operSeq[xorArray[j+1]];
  }
  operSeq >>= 1;
  operSeq[4]  = bit[4]; 
  keyRej.push_back(bit[4]);
 }
 while (turnSeq != inpSeq);
 for (unsigned int k = 0; k < keyRej.size(); k++)
 cout << keyRej[k];
}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing what types `xorArray`,`operSeq`,`bit`, etc. are, my crystal ball is currently under repair ...

Comment: Segmentation faults are very difficult to diagnose (except in certain special cases that do not apply here) without a *complete* program that we can compile for ourselves and watch crash.  Have you tried `valgrind`?

Comment: I will try to post a link to my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to compare `j` with `xorArray.size(`) here:

```
for ( unsigned int j=0; xorArray.size(); j=j+2 )
```

as a result your cycle is never ends and you read beyond the array boundaries.

===========================================================
Also this cycle can run infinitely:

```
while (turnSeq != inpSeq);
```

because the cycle condition is never changed (unless you change it from another thread);

Comment: Thank you, the program is correctly compiled, it was compiled before I make the for fix. But now instead of "Segmentation fault" I have no output. I will try to post a link to my code.

Comment: @Mohamed please see my addition. That may cause your second problem.

Comment: Ok, I am finally having what seems to be a valid output, even if it was not correct thought. I was saying ' While (turnSeq != inpSeq)' I was supposed to say 'While (operSeq != inpSeq)'. Now I will check if the output is correct.